# load product in particular category in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am creating navigation for my store. I am new to magento. I am having problem to load product under that category. It is possible for me to print all product under all categories but I don't know how to load products under its specific category.

This is my code

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml($this->getSelectedCategoryId(), 0, 'level-top') ?>
<?php
if ($this->getTitle() != '') {
    $title = $this->getTitle();
} else {
    $title = 'Categories';
}
?>
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
        <div class="block vertical-menu">   
            <div class="title-block" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><h4><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></h4></div>  
            <div class="block-content">
                <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);?>
                <ul class="content-navigation">
                    <?php foreach($children as $category){ ?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrlPath(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>
                        <? foreach($category->getId()){ ?> // here I want to load product as per their category
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('mpanel')->acceptToUsePanel()): ?>
        <div class="block vertical-menu">   
            <div class="block-title"><strong><span><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></span></strong></div>    
            <div class="block-content">
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Have no categories.'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use following code

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(' Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() '); //You will get current category id use passing value.
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $product)
{
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

It work..

Comment: so now how do I print $productCollection?

Comment: you will get all product of specific category in `$productCollection`

Comment: ok what i did now took your code and added this  '<?php $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); ?>
       <?php foreach($prod as $productCollection){ ?>
       <li><a href="#"><?php echo $prod->getName(); ?></a></li>
       <?php }?>'

Comment: how to use passing value? and where?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$category' (T_VARIABLE) $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(' Mage::registry('$category')->getId() ');    this is how I wrote

Comment: @NewBeeInMagento Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(' Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() ') How catalog/product model will load a category???